# PHP/PEAR SearchReplace - String is "varyingText" - How to replace "varyingText" with "newVaryingText"?

Tags: php, pear, replace

I have a simple application based on the php pear class SearchReplace:

```
// Define result of Activate click
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Activate')
{   
    include "$docRoot/includes/pear/SearchReplace.php" ;
    $files = array( "$docRoot/promotions/index.php" ) ;
    $snr = new File_SearchReplace( '$promoChange = "";', '$promoChange = "'.$currentYear.'/'.$currentPromotion.'";', $files) ;
    $snr -> doSearch() ;
}
```

Notice the string that it is configured to search for:

`$promoChange = "";`

What I need to do, is replace this string, when there is a varying value assigned to the variable `$promoChange` So basically, what I am trying to replace would look something like this:

`$promoChange = "2011/sep-oct";`

I would need something along the lines of:

`$promoChange = "%";`

What would be the correct way of doing this?

If anyone has any input in this matter, it would be appreciated greatly,

Thank You!

Comment: You would need a regex then, not a static string replacement function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the file and replace using regex manually. The regex you need probably looks something like:

```
$text = preg_replace(
    '/\$promoChange = "[^"]*";/',
    '$promoChange = "' . $currentYear . '/' . $currentPromotion . '"',
    $text
);
```

I would caution against using something like this for anything more complicated.